# How to deal with the datasource when there is no data in POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am getting the data, transform and display in a powerbi report. However some days, there is no data at all and this is creating a problem during a transformation step. Since PowerBI stops retrying after some time. The next, my reports doesn't work. I am not an expert on PowerBI and  I am looking for any ideas

Comment: You should look into mquery and understand where the problem is coming from..

Comment: Can you calrify by what you mean by no data, for example the file/table is missing or not there or the file/table is there but with no rows. As I may have solution for the file/table is missing

Answer (score 0):

I would go to your datasource... say it's a database... then I'd make all the fields that are causing you grief to be **NOT NULL**. Then your Power BI report will never have to figure out what to do when it encounters a NULL field.